# Creating an array of `nothing` of any size in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia it is possible to create arrays of any size using the functions `zeros(.)` or `ones(.)`. Is there a similar function to create an array that is filled with `nothing` at initialization but also accepts floats? I mean a function like in this example:

```
a = array_of_nothing(3)
# a = [nothing,nothing,nothing]
a[1] = 3.14
# a = [3.14,nothing,nothing]
```

I tried to find information on internet, but without success... Sorry, I am a beginner in Julia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fill` function can be used to create arrays of arbitrary values, but it's not so easy to use here, since you want a `Vector{Union{Float64, Nothing}}`. Two options come to mind:

A comprehension:

```
a = Union{Float64, Nothing}[nothing for _ in 1:3];
a[2] = 3.14;

>> a
3-element Array{Union{Nothing, Float64},1}:
  nothing
 3.14    
  nothing
```

Or ordinary array initialization:

```
a = Vector{Union{Float64, Nothing}}(undef, 3)
fill!(a, nothing)
a[2] = 3.14
```

It seems that when you do `Vector{Union{Float64, Nothing}}(undef, 3)` the vector automatically contains `nothing`, but I wouldn't rely on that, so `fill!` may be necessary.

Comment: You can just write `Vector{Union{Float64, Nothing}}(nothing, 3)`. Regarding relying on what `undef` produces, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/31091#discussion_r263588660. If you mix singleton with non-singleton you will get a singleton.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for the `Base.fill` — Function.

```
fill(x, dims)
```

This creates an array filled with value x.

```
println(fill("nothing", (1,3)))
```

You can also pass a function `Foo()` like `fill(Foo(), dims)` which will return an array filled with the result of evaluating `Foo()` once.

Comment: I see that the example with `Foo()` is mentioned in the docs, but I don't really get it. `Foo()` is a value, not a function, so it not clear why anyone would expect it to be different from `x = Foo(); fill(x, dims)`, or what's so special about this usage.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that `Foo()` can return an object reference and all elements created by fill will point to the same object. Also, I feel this is more convenient.

Comment: But how is that different from `fill(x, dims)` when `x` is an object reference?

Comment: I have to run some test to analyze if there is any difference. I think its just mostly for convenience to avoid the creation of an extra variable.

Comment: There's no difference. My point is that `Foo()` is not a function, but a value, that is output from the function `Foo`. The point in the documentation is, I think, to explain what happens when that value is an object reference, since that behaviour is often surprising.

Comment: Why do think the behavior is surprising?

Comment: I don't think it's surprising, but lots of new users do. There are many questions on SO concerning this, and also on Julia Discourse.